XMLRPC on docker with php8.0-cli
I want to use xmlrpc on dokcer php-cli. I have successfully installed it on docker php:8.0-fpm with this commands:
RUN pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/xmlrpc-1.0.0RC3
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xmlrpc

When executing the same commands on php:8.0-cli-alpine, it is installed properly during docker build, but the container doesn't detect it:
php -a
php > var_dump(function_exists('xmlrpc_encode_request'));
bool(false)

Is there any other special thing I should do for php-cli?
Thanks
Tried installed xmlrpc but wasn't installed properly

This function might have changed in the php8. The documentations does not list 8.0 as a supported version https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode-request.php

You might try as well using the phpxmlrpc/polyfill-xmlrpc package instead, installing it via Composer. It is a pure-php reimplementation of the same API as the extension.
